# $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ has equal roots $\implies$ $a,b,c$ are in G.P.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a,b,c$ be three nonzero real numbers such that. If $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ has equal roots, then prove that $a,b,c$ are in G.P.

My approach: If roots are equal then $b^2=4ac$

But criteria for $a,b,c$ to be in G.P. is $b^2=ac$

I can't figure out how $a,b,c$ are in G.P.

Comment: What do you mean by "G.P."? General Position?

Comment: You are right, they are not.

Comment: @RobertLewis: G.P = geometric progression

Comment: Oh!  ***G*** eometric ***P*** roportion!  OK, progression!

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is correct if 
$$f(x) = a x^2+2 b x + c$$
Note the $2$ in front of $b$.
Then clearly $b^2=ac$ Hence
$$ a/b=b/c$$